# How to dynamic add image url to src textbox TinyMCE - Image plgin

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I have image Url from my upload, how to paste this image url to src textbox by tinyMCE api?

[image]

Comment: However, I use jQuery selector to get this element `$('.mce-window .mce-container-body input:first')`

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but with people still visiting it and with no correct answer, Let me give it a shot.

If your image was uploaded via tinymce, returning your image url (location) as a json object from your php upload script should fill your tinymce source field automatically.

Hoping your php upload file is called postAcceptor.php

TinyMce

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
  automatic_uploads: false
});
```

php

```
// from postAcceptor.php, do all your upload logic.
// return a location json object formated like { "location": "folder/sub-  folder/new-location.png" }
// Jsonencode an array to get such a json object
$result = array('location'=>'/images/uploadedfile.png');
echo json_encode($result);
return;
```

Answer (score -1):

Paste the *image url* in the **Source field**

For example if the image is accessible at `localhost:3000/my_images/LOGO.png`

then the *url*  to be used at **Source field** must be `/report_designer_images/heart.gif`

This works good for me with `tinymce 4` on `rails 2`.